# Dynamically creating a comment form

Tags: jquery, ajax, comments

I want to implement an ajax commenting system.

Currently, each comment has a *reply* button on it which *onclick* creates a reply form. The reply form is created using an ajax request, and this is what I want to change.

I noticed that here in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com), when you click on *add comment*, the comment form opens **immediatly** and not by an **ajax request**.

So my question is - **what's the best way to achieve this**?
I don't need code, just the basic idea

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the best, but you could have a div tag or some other element that your onClick fills with content.

Answer (score 0):

Just set hidden elements in DOM that are show/hide on specific action as click/mouseover or whatelse.

Comment: That's not very efficient though, creating many reply forms for each comment when only 0-1 of them will be used

Comment: Of course, you have to use DOM manipulation too, using detach/append or whatever.